# How to process sub-lists separately?

Tags: python-2.7

I have following list of lists:

```
e = [[2,4,5],[3,2,4],[3,1,5]]
```

I want to grab values less than 2.5 in each sub-list and distribute their sum to the rest of values in the sub-list. Then get maximum value out of each sub-list (3 final values). I am trying following but to no avail:

```
l = sum([i for i in e if i < 2.5])
k = [i for i in e if i > 2.5] # to distribute smaller values
j = l/len(k)
m = max([i+j for i in k])
```

So output should look like this:

```
[[6],[5],[5.5]]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciative.

Comment: What does it mean "distribute their sum to the rest of values in the sub-list"?

Comment: @beroe: sum of values lesser than 2.5 divided equally over values greater than 2.5

Comment: give us an output example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to wrap your code into a loop that works on each sub-list:

```
mainlist = [[2,4,5],[3,2,4],[3,1,5]]

m = []
for e in mainlist:
    l = sum([i for i in e if i < 2.5])
    k = [i for i in e if i >= 2.5] # to distribute smaller values
    j = float(l)/len(k)
    newlist = [x + j for x in k]
    m.append(max(newlist))

print m
```

Output:

```
[6.0, 5.0, 5.5]
```

Comment: it return following error for this line: newlist = [x + j for x in k]

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list

Comment: Great. You did 99% of the work and almost had it going. Yes, you have to be careful re-using names inside list-comprehension because the values persist.... P.S. if you want list format like `[[6],[5],[5.5]]` you can just add brackets: `.append([max()])` instead of `.append(max())`

Answer (score 0):

With this you can grab all the values that are less than 2.5

```
        lessThanNum = []

        for values in e:
            for subvalues in e:
                if subvalues < 2.5:
                   lessThanNum.append(subvalues) # get all values less than 2.5
```

I dont understand yet what you mean by "sum of values lesser than 2.5 divided equally over values greater than 2."

Comment: for example: if i have [2,3,4], then 2 is less than 2.5 and length remaining values is 2. So 2/len(values > 2.5). Then add it each value which is greater than 2.5